# Netsuite: Saved Search Formula : Show Distinct Line with Earliest Custom Date

Tags: mysql, sql, formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to get a saved search to only show one of each item. I do not want duplicates of the same item on this search. I only want the item with the earliest "Due @ Dest" field to be on there.
This search show all items that are out of stock and what PO# (containers) are coming in, along with what items and what date they are arriving. In the image below I would like it to not display the 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th line because these items are already on the search with a more recent date.
Apologies if this sounds confusing, let me know if there is anything I can make clearer. I imagine i would need a custom formula. Any idea where to start?
-  Brandon

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with grouping and using the "When Ordered By Field."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter so you only get one row per item:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.due_at_dest = (select min(t2.due_at_dest)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.item = t.item
                      );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  
I'm not entirely familiar with SQL, is t supposed to be the table or a certain colum / row?   And if this goes on the criteria page (im assuming as a date formula) what would be my condition for it? Below if my updated script.  

select t.*
from t
where t.{custbody_due_dest} = (select min{custbody_due_dest}
                       from t t2                       
                      where t2.{item}= t.{item} 
                      );

Comment: @BrandonReale . . . You don't mention the table name in your question, so I invented a short one called `t`.

Comment: Right, but I don't know if netsuite needs to call tables, I think it assumes any query's you make retain to the search your calling it from. The internal ID for my search would be 2214 , but i don't think netsuite would need to call that since the query is already in the search.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you are using the ODBC, NetSuite limits our use of SQL within its user interface and suitescript, and select statements do not work. NetSuite converts the Results tab into a select statement and the Criteria tab into the where clause.